# Как используя Entity Framework создавать в таблице динамические поля

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Нужно создать интернет магазин с возможностью создавать категории с дополнительными полями для продуктов. И при создании продукта чтобы была возможность заполнять дополнительные поля категории. Как это сделать? Есть идея реализовать это с помощью добавления в модель списка, но как?

Comment: Таблица создаётся sql-запросом `create table`.

Comment: Отлично я в курсе, а как передавать название и тип данных каждый раз разный?

Comment: Комментарии никто не видит. Никто! Хотите, чтобы люди увидели ваше дополнение - редактируйте вопрос. Он всплывёт на первую страницу сайта, его снова увидят. / Если хотите обратиться лично к кому-то, добавляйте знак `@` перед его ником.

Comment: Начнём с того, что создавать таблицы в процессе выполнения (в рантайме) нужно лишь в том случае, если вы пишете приложение-оболочку для работы с СУБД, наподобие Management Studio, pgAdmin и т. п. / В обычном приложении таблицы всегда создаются на этапе проектирования. Далее структура БД остаётся неизменной. В одной таблице можно хранить миллионы строк. Оставьте затею создавать по таблице на каждого пользователя.

Comment: Как передавать название и тип? А как вы данные передаёте через API в запросы другого типа, наподобие `select`, `insert`? Вот точно также! / Однако, название таблицы нельзя задать в виде параметра sql, поэтому запрос вида `create table` нужно делать конкатенацией строк, с обязательной проверкой на валидность.

Comment: И последнее. В тегах стоит  метка entity-framework. С его помощью нельзя создавать таблицы в рантайме, это можно делать только на чистом sql. Поэтому про LINQ даже не заикайтесь. При использовании EF структура БД описывается до компиляции кода.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, а как реализовать так чтобы используя модели, сделать возможность добавлять каждый раз разные поля? Просто тут задание дали такое реализовать с использованием entity framework, такой вызов так сказать

Comment: Не спрашивайте в комментариях! Редактируйте вопрос.

Comment: JSON хранить не вариант?

Comment: Этот теперь совсем другой вопрос, полностью отличный от первоначального. Его следовало задать отдельно, создав новую тему.

Comment: Как создать поля? - Ответ: никак. EF - сущность времени компиляции. Усвойте наконец разницу между процессом разработки и процессом выполнения.

Comment: Вам именно новые **поля** нужны? Или всё же новые записи в таблице Категории?

Comment: Как уже посоветовали, посмотрите на колонки типа json или xml. / Также гляньте [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, точно никак, а если в модель добавить List?

Comment: List мапится на другую таблицу, в которой будут **строки**. Я же говорю: определитесь, что вам надо.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, я определился, пробую создавать List